# wire an underwater pool light

Tags: light

I need help in connecting my underwater pool light which uses 24/3 to a switch which suppies power with a 14/3 line. supply line black wire is hot. I have the white wires pigtailed together. not certain where the incoming red wire or the red wire to the light go. As well as where the black wire to the lilght goes.

Comment: Is this a wet-niche, dry-niche, or no-niche pool light?

Comment: the niche is underwater but is sealed

Comment: Better yet, can you get us a make/model or a link to the instructions for this pool light of yours?

Comment: I think it is a hayward SP 540 that is the marking on the lens. The light stopped working after a storm and I removed the switch (and like an idiot) didn't mark the wiring. I got a replacement bulb and need to reconnect the wires.